# Copia diaria automática de base de datos mysql en windows XP

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, windows, phpmyadmin

Tengo una base de datos mysql alojada en un servidor que corre con Windows Xp y empleo phpmyadmin para gestionarla.

Actualmente hago copias de seguridad manualmente mediante phpmyadmin, pero me gustaria saber alguna forma de automatizar este proceso, es decir, que el servidor me genere automáticamente una copia de seguridad diaria.

He visto scripts para servidores Linux, pero no doy encontrado la manera para hacerlo con Windows XP.

Alguien me puede ayudar?

Gracias,

Comment: puedes hacer un comando por lotes **.bat** que ejecute la instruccion de **mysqldump** correspondiente, y luego en el programador de tareas añades una para ejecutar ese archivo .bat.

Comment: @Angel Cid No entiendo porque no pones ese comentario como respuesta, pues creo que ese seria su lugar.

Comment: @nachfren lo considero más bien una idea para que busque como solucionarlo. Realmente una respuesta seria un ejemplo con un archivo .bat, ver como se hace una tarea programada en windows...

Comment: Puedes usar Synctoy, es una herramienta gratuita de Microsoft y junto con el automatizador de tareas funcionaría muy bien.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este archivo .bat me funciona en w7. Y le inclui entre las tareas programadas de Windows, para que me ejecute en forma diaria. Espero te sirva.

Archivo **BackupMysql.bat**

```
for /f %%u in ('date /t') do set d=%%u
for /f %%u in ('time /t') do set t=%%u
if "%t:~1,1%"==":" set t=0%t%
set timestr=%d:~6,4%%d:~3,2%%d:~0,2%%t:~0,2%%t:~3,2%

cd C:\Users\lanadmin\Desktop\Backup_db_MySql
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump --user=root --password=MiPassword --databases MiDB > copia_db_MiDB_%timestr%.sql
```

El cd es para ubicarme en el directorio destino del backup
Tambien necesita de un user y password valido, MiDB debe ser la base de datos que necesitar hace el backup.

Answer (score 3):

Me valío el [comentario de Angel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76229/copia-diaria-autom%C3%A1tica-de-base-de-datos-mysql-en-windows-xp#comment140191_76229) como respuesta:

> puedes hacer un comando por lotes **.bat** que ejecute la instruccion de **mysqldump** correspondiente, y luego en el programador de tareas añades una para ejecutar ese archivo .bat.

Creé el siguiente archivo .bat:

```
echo off
cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin
mysqldump nombrebasededatos -u root > C:\COPIA_SEGURIDAD\BASEDEDATOS\%Date:~6,4%%Date:~3,2%%Date:~0,2%nombrebasededatos.sql
```

Y luego programé una tarea que ejecutara este archivo diariamente.